# Global Styles don't work on resetting the margins

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I am using `styled-components` in a react app. For the global styles I have the following code

```
import { createGlobalStyle } from 'styled-components';
import normalize from 'normalize.css';

export default createGlobalStyle`
    ${normalize}

    *, *::after, *::before{
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
`;
```

but when I use `h1` in the `App` component like so

```
function App() {
  return <h1>Hello</h1>;
}

export default App;
```

there will be margin on `h1`.

In the DevTools in styles I have the following css rule

```
h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
    margin: 0.67em 0;
}
```

from `normalize.css:40`, and the margin in the Global Styles is overwritten because it's crossed through. Why? and how to force the margin on all elements to be 0 as I wish it to be?

EDIT: this is the code on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/pedantic-stallman-06zls?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: What's in normalize.css? Please create a [mcve] like codesandbox

Comment: I added the codesandbox link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/):

> The universal selector (`*`) has no specificity value `(0,0,0,0)`

This is why the selector `h1` from normalize is applied since it has a higher specificity of `(0,0,0,1)`

You could update your selector like the following to ensure it overrides normalize:

```
export default createGlobalStyle`
${normalize}

*, *::after, *::before, h1:is(h1){
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
`;
```

The `:is(h1)` part is added only to increase specificity of selector.

[image: Edit relaxed-glade-y6f99]

Comment: I looked up `:is()` and I understand it matches any element in its argument. But what exactly `h1:is(h1)` means here? Why don't I just include `h1` alone? This is the first time I come across this selector

Comment: @BlackMath *"Why don't I just include h1 alone"* - you can try this in sandbox and see the normalize `h1` style will still win. So you need a way to increase your selectors specificity. If the selector was a class or id you could simply repeat it like `.myClass.myClass`, but that doesn't work with a tag selector. Using  `h1:not(_)`,  `h1:is` etc is just a trick to increase selector specificity while still targeting the original element